# Handling an unimplemented argument in Python

Tags: python

I have a method with the following signature

```
def read_a_file(file_name, line_number=False):
    if line_number:
       raise NotImplementedError
    # CODE TO READ THE FILE
```

The argument `line_number` has not been implemented yet though I plan to do it soon. I would like to make this clear to end users when they try to call `read_a_file()` with some value for line_number greater than 0.

Would it be correct to raise a `NotImplementedError` or is there some better way to notify the callers ?

Answer (score 5):

It's quite strange behaviour to have an argument on a function that you do not want people to use — why not just add it when it *is* implemented?

Nobody will miss something which isn't there and it's likely to just add more confusion. The parameter will be suggested by autocomplete tools and only be identifiable as unsupported once code is run.

If you still *do* want to do this, I would provide a bit more informative message for the exception, e.g.

```
def read_a_file(file_name, line_number=False):
    if line_number:
        raise NotImplementedError("line_number parameter is not yet supported.")
```